Como inicializar un Swal con propiedades dinamicas
actualmente uso la librería Sweet Alert 2 para preguntar al usuario si esta seguro que desea activar o desactivar algo.
var toggle = $(this);
    var isActive = false;
    isActive = toggle.hasClass('checkactive');
    var text = isActive ? 'desactivar' : 'activar';

swal({
        title: '¿Esta seguro que quiere ' + text+ '?',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        type: 'warning',
        input: "textarea",
        inputPlaceholder: 'Ingrese el motivo (Maximo 100 caracteres)',
        inputValidator: function (value) {
            if (!value) {
                return "Debe ingresar un motivo, o cancelar la acción.";
            }
            if (value.length > 100) {
                return "El motivo de tener menos que 100 caracteres";
            }
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.dismiss) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'a/ajax.setState.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    id: toggle.attr('id').split("_").pop(),
                    estado: !isActive,
                    motivo: result.value
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response.type === true) {
                    if (isActive) {
                        toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                    } else {
                        toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (response.fix === true) {
                        if (isActive) {
                            toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                        } else {
                            toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                        }
                    }
                    new Noty({
                        text: 'Hubo un problema al editar el objeto. <br>' + response.msg,
                        type: 'error'
                    }).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

Pero me di cuenta que solo necesito que el usuario escriba el motivo cuando va desactivar algo.
Revisé la documentación pero lamentablemente no hay muchos ejemplos acerca del método Swal.update({...options}) que te permite la actualización de las propiedades del swal.
Alguien sabe como definir las propiedades del swal antes de que se ejecute con esta estructura?

Deberias agregar tu HTML

Puedes usar la misma condicion que tienes dentro de la propiedad input asi:


$("#test").click(function() {
var toggle = $(this);
    var isActive = false;
    isActive = toggle.hasClass('checkactive');
    toggle.toggleClass('checkactive')
    var text = isActive ? 'desactivar' : 'activar';

swal.fire({
        title: '¿Esta seguro que quiere ' + text+ '?',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        type: 'warning',
        input: isActive ? "textarea" : "",
        inputPlaceholder: 'Ingrese el motivo (Maximo 100 caracteres)',
        inputValidator: function (value) {
            if (!value) {
                return "Debe ingresar un motivo, o cancelar la acción.";
            }
            if (value.length > 100) {
                return "El motivo de tener menos que 100 caracteres";
            }
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.dismiss) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'a/ajax.setState.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    id: toggle.attr('id').split("_").pop(),
                    estado: !isActive,
                    motivo: result.value
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response.type === true) {
                    if (isActive) {
                        toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                    } else {
                        toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (response.fix === true) {
                        if (isActive) {
                            toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                        } else {
                            toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                        }
                    }
                    new Noty({
                        text: 'Hubo un problema al editar el objeto. <br>' + response.msg,
                        type: 'error'
                    }).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script></script>
<button class="checkactive" id="test">alert</button>




Lamentablemente la forma en la que tengo implementado SweetAlert 2 no reconoce el método fire(), pero encontré como alternativa separar el array de las propiedades y definirlo dinámicamente.

Encontre una solución:
Definí por separado el array de propiedades del swal para inicializarlo dinámicamente.
var toggle = $(this);
var isActive = false;
isActive = toggle.hasClass('checkactive');
var text = isActive ? 'desactivar' : 'activar';
var flagPropieties = isActive ? {
                title: '¿Esta seguro que quiere ' + text+ ' la API?',
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                type: 'warning',
                input: 'textarea',
                inputPlaceholder: 'Ingrese el motivo (Maximo 100 caracteres)',
                inputValidator: function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return "Debe ingresar un motivo, o cancelar la acción.";
                    }
                    if (value.length > 100) {
                        return "El motivo debe tener maximo 100 caracteres";
                    }
                }
            } : {
            title: '¿Esta seguro que quiere ' + text+ ' la API?',
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            type: 'warning'
        };
swal({flagPropieties ).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.dismiss) {
let motivo = isActive ? result.value : 'Se activa API';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'a/ajax.setState.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    id: toggle.attr('id').split("_").pop(),
                    estado: !isActive,
                    motivo: motivo 
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response.type === true) {
                    if (isActive) {
                        toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                    } else {
                        toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (response.fix === true) {
                        if (isActive) {
                            toggle.removeClass('checkactive');
                        } else {
                            toggle.addClass('checkactive');
                        }
                    }
                    new Noty({
                        text: 'Hubo un problema al editar el objeto. <br>' + response.msg,
                        type: 'error'
                    }).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

